# Converted CS3 project to CS5, and now I get a cannot find GraphicsPath compile error

Tags: flash, flash-cs5

I have converted my CS3 project to CS5, and when I compile, I receive the following errors

1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: GraphicsPath.
 1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: IGraphicsData.

It doesn't point to any specific code anywhere, which made me think that it was a library entity that was causing the issue.  However, when I copy over the entire library to a new FLA, it compiles fine (though with not content obviously)

I have a couple locations in code where I do some bitmap data and sprite graphics drawing by code, which I thought may be the issue.  I commented these sections out and made sure to comment out the relevant includes as well, however this had no effect on the issue.

The flash dev center doesn't have much information on what these entities are, other than base graphics classes used when doing things like fill and gradients.  It also says nothing about their inter-compatibility between CS3 and CS5.

Has anyone had a similar issue?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to target Flash V10.1.  When you let CS5 convert a project from CS3 to CS5, it must replace the movieclip entities in the library with CS3 instances which require CS5 base classed (like IGraphicsData).  But the upconversion does not change the target Flash version.,  which causes the issue since Flash 9 does not have IGraphicsPath.

So the solution is to target 10.1 if you have upconverted your CS3 project to a CS5 project and are seeing the above error.

Thanks to TheDarkIn1978 for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

did you forget to import those classes?

```
import flash.display.GraphicsPath;
import flash.display.IGraphicsData;
```

Comment: I have no idea where I would import them.  None of my classes make any use of them.  Should I be importing them in each class that does anything with a sprite or bitmap's graphics entity?  Was that something that was implicit in CS3 but made explicit in CS5?

Comment: yah   I tried importing them in every single class I have.  No luck.  Perhaps its an issue with some element in the library.  I guess this is just going to be a very long guess and check process.

Comment: well, no, but they're new since Flash Player 10.  are you targeting Flash Player 9?  if so try targeting 10.1 to see if those errors go away.